# Messed up numpy installation - `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found bug

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, miniconda

Up untill two days ago everything was fine with my machine, then I happened to manually build ffmpeg and installed its dependencies too manually. Now within a virtualenv numpy loading is failing with this error :

`` ImportError: /home/koustuv/miniconda/lib/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3) ``

I have tried in my normal conda installation without virtualenv and it is working fine, but within a new virtualenv (even with setting python location to the Ubuntu one other than miniconda one) numpy is failing to import with this weird error. Tried to install gfortan but its already in the newest package. Please help! all assignments are stuck :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround that worked for me is:

```
conda remove libgfortran
conda install libgcc --force
```

If you want more details, check [this issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/686), where I found the solution.

Comment: Worked also for me: Theano code implemented in Jupyter notebook launched in Anaconda / Python 3.5 virtual environment  :-D

Comment: This also solved the problem for me (using Anaconda with Python 2.7 over Jupyter notebook). Thanks.